# Flot visitors per day weird plotting issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I have been having some really odd issues while trying to plot my website visitor data. I am using flots "visitors per day with zooming and weekends" example to build my own graph of visitors that visit my website. I generate identically formatted data for the plot and this is what I get (see link for picture).

Picture link: http://picpaste.com/flot_issue-sJ0X36HA.png

as you can see, There is a line under the peak that should not be there. If anyone knows how to fix this I would appreciate it!

here is the data I am using to plot the points:

[[1374273300000, 1], [1374274740000, 1], [1374275640000, 1], [1374276300000, 2], [1374277020000, 1], [1374254460000, 1], [1374254940000, 1], [1374255300000, 1], [1374255720000, 1], [1374256740000, 1], [1374258120000, 1], [1374258240000, 1], [1374259620000, 1], [1374260340000, 1], [1374261300000, 1], [1374261600000, 1], [1374261660000, 1], [1374262200000, 1], [1374262380000, 1], [1374262860000, 1], [1374263880000, 1], [1374264600000, 1], [1374265740000, 1], [1374266400000, 1], [1374266520000, 1], [1374266940000, 1], [1374268080000, 1], [1374268920000, 1], [1374315660000, 1], [1374320520000, 1], [1374278520000, 1], [1374278820000, 1], [1374280980000, 1], [1374325260000, 1], [1374282420000, 1], [1374325620000, 1], [1374326220000, 1], [1374326340000, 1], [1374326700000, 1], [1374327300000, 1], [1374288780000, 1], [1374289980000, 1], [1374290400000, 1], [1374291060000, 1], [1374293820000, 1], [1374294060000, 1], [1374299280000, 1], [1374302520000, 1], [1374303180000, 1], [1374303240000, 1], [1374303780000, 1], [1374304200000, 1], [1374307560000, 1], [1374308400000, 1], [1374309660000, 1], [1374311280000, 1]]

Thank you,
John

Comment: It would probably be better if you posted a jsFiddle or a live example to make it easier for others to investigate the issue.

Comment: Post some code or a Fiddle like @MasterAM mentioned, there's nothing to fix if we don't know how that graph is being generated.

Comment: In case you don't know: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your data is not properly sorted.  Flot will not order your x values for you.

Comment: @Mark I did not realize the data was not sorted. I noticed I forgot to sort the data coming from my databases. After sorting and retrying the flot graph page it worked perfectly. Thanks for pointing out that issue.

Comment: @Louis93 Thank you very much about informing me about jsfiddle I have not dabbled to heavily in web programming since I am an x86 assembler/C++/Verilog developper. It will help me a lot in the future.